# Make a function in .replace()

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following code that uses a regex:

```
var mystring = "<<cool>> <<stuff>>"
var regexString = /<<([^\:]{0,})>>/gi

mystring.replace(regexString, "$1")
```

I would like to be able to replace the string based on the text I get back on the capture group. Something like:

```
var mystring = "<<cool>> <<stuff>>"
var regexString = /<<([^>]{1,})>>/gi

mystring.replace(regexString, function(var0) { //var0 being the text from the capture group

    if(var0 == "cool") {
        console.log("got cool")

    } else {
        console.log("didn't get cool")
    }
})
```

Is there someway to do this?

Comment: The 1st argument will be the entire match. Each capture group will add an additional argument after that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely use a function as a second argument of `.replace()`. For example:

```
mystring.replace(regexString, function(match, group1) { 
    // do anything with group1 here
});
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: This is great. How would I go about learning how to do this in the future? Is this an attribute of .replace() or of regular expressions in javascript?

Comment: Sure, here is the reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace